# Pasting multiple slide ranges with ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting") results in only the last one beeing pasted

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Im am creating a PowerPoint Add-In in Visual Basic with Visual Studio as VSTO Add-In. With one of the buttons in my Add-In I want to add slides from two different presentations to my current one while keeping the original source formatting. I use  `CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")` for my function but apparently PowerPoint pastes the slides at the very end of the `Sub` procedure and not when the function is called.

**My code looks like this:**

```
Private Sub ButtonInsertSong_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles ButtonInsertSong.Click

        Dim srcPath1 As String = "" 'would be an absolute path
        Dim srcPath2 As String = "" 'would be an other absolute path

        Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim destPPT As Presentation
        Dim srcPPT1 As Presentation
        Dim srcPPT2 As Presentation

        pptApp = GetObject([Class]:="PowerPoint.Application")

        destPPT = pptApp.ActivePresentation
        srcPPT1 = pptApp.Presentations.Open(srcPath1, MsoTriState.msoTrue,, MsoTriState.msoFalse)
        srcPPT2 = pptApp.Presentations.Open(srcPath2, MsoTriState.msoTrue,, MsoTriState.msoFalse)

        srcPPT1.Slides.Range().Copy()
        pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
        'pptApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus()
        'destPPT.Save()

        srcPPT2.Slides.Range().Copy()
        pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")
        'pptApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus()
        'destPPT.Save()

        srcPPT1.Close()
        srcPPT2.Close()

    End Sub
```

I found two similar problems where they suggested either using `CommandBars.ReleaseFocus()` which didnt change anything for me. The other solution would be to save the current presentation each time after pasting some slides to it which would work in theory but I want this Add-In to work with a newly created presentation which has not been saved before and therefore doesnt have a name or path yet.

I thought of a third option which I havent tried out yet but I guess it would work. I would create a new temporary presentation where I can paste both slide ranges seperately and save the temporary presentation twice. After that I would copy the slides from the temporary presentation to the current one and I guess this should work fine but it would be pretty slow to do this.

So now I am wondering if there is a way to force the `ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")` to execute right after beeing called wihtout saving my presentation so I dont have to do some weird extra work which slows down the whole process.

Comment: Do you get the same results when doing the same manually?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev What exactly do you mean by manually? Like opening both files from the explorer, selecting all slides and hitting ctrl+c and ctrl+v in the other presentation? Or dont use `ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting")` and rather use `destPPT.Slides.Paste()` and change all the attributes of the slides?

Comment: Manually means without any code, by using the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Well yes, thats how it was done for the last years and it obviously works but I want to automate it because the slides I copy are from a folder with several hundreds of different presentations and it takes some time to get the right one.

Comment: Sounds like the difference is where the active slide or object in the target presentation `destPPT`, so you may try to activate the place first where the content should be pasted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252516/discussion-between-joel-and-eugene-astafiev).